# Limit/filter tabs in DocuSign "Sender View"?

Tags: rest, docusignapi

Using the V2 DocuSign REST API, when requesting the URL for the Sender View, is it possible to filter out or limit in any way, the tabs which are available to use? By default, the following are available:

[image]

For example, in a DocuSign integration I'm working on, if I don't want users to be able to use the "Signer Attachment" tab, is it possible to prevent it from showing up? The [documentation](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm?utm_campaign=DevCenter%20Nurture%20Campaign%20Email%201%20-%20Key%20Information&utm_medium=email&utm_source=Eloqua#REST%20API%20References/Post%20Sender%20View.htm%3FTocPath%3DREST%2520API%2520References%7C_____79) only lists one parameter for the method, which is a `returnUrl`, so that tells me it is not likely possible to do what I want, but I wanted to verify there wasn't another way.

Comment: I'll let others chime in here, but as far as I know this is not currently supported (ie limiting which tabs show up in the palette when opening an embedded sending view).

Comment: Thanks. That is what I assumed but wasn't 100%.

Comment: You probably have others you want to limit, but the specific Signer Attachment example should be able to be controlled through the "Signer Attachments" option.  There's an account level setting under Features, and also the same setting under Permission Profiles.  Unchecking it does remove the "Signer Attachment" choice.

Comment: Interesting! Yes there are others I'd like to filter out as well but that is good to know!

Comment: I see there are some other choices down under "New Features" of the Feature section that could apply.  I'm sure this is account wide so probably only works for you if you have no other use for them within the account you're working with.

Comment: Meant to reference the names.  "Enable Tag Type Data Field", "Enable Tag Type Radio Button", etc...  They're greyed out for me so likely something DocuSign has to adjust for you.  I've never messed with them

Comment: Thanks. It looks like that sums it up. If you want to post that info in an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summarizing the comments that apply:

The only controls available are to disable certain tag types from the account or permission profile.  The specific Signer Attachment example should be able to be controlled through the "Signer Attachments" option. There's an account level setting under Features, and also the same setting under Permission Profiles. Unchecking it does remove the "Signer Attachment" choice.

Then at the account level only there are other choices down under "New Features" of the Feature section. I'm sure this is account wide so probably only works for you if you have no other use for them within the account you're working with.  They are named  "Enable Tag Type Data Field", "Enable Tag Type Radio Button", etc...